# Using static, internal and protected access modifiers in interfaces c# 8

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

C# 8 now supports access modifiers on interface members, and its usage confuses me. Take the following example

```cs
public interface IFoobar 
{   // these members are all valid
    protected string Protected { get; set; }
    internal string Internal { get; set; }
    static string Static { get; set; }
}

public class Foobar : IFoobar // <-- error, Internal and Protected members not implemented
{
    protected string Protected { get; set; }
    internal string Internal { get; set; }
    static string Static { get; set; } // only this one implements IFoobar
}
```

My expectation was that `Foobar` above would fully implement `IFoobar`. However that is only the case for `Static`, the other ones don't.

Can someone

- explain why they behave different (and also different from pre-c#8 interface members)
- give me a use-case for each of the three modifiers in an interface like this?

Thanks

[edit]

I am aware that using explicit interface implementation will implement the members, but for pre-c#8 interface members that wasn't strictly the only way. Why is this different with the new members?

Comment: It looks like you need to implement those members explicitly. `string IFoobar.Protected {get;set;}`

Comment: Could you link the source you got this example from?

Comment: @Christopher I wrote down the example myself

Comment: That is standard [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)

Comment: It looks like [this LDM](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-04-18.md#implicitly-implementing-non-public-interface-members) decision resulted in the explicit implementation requirement for access modified default interface methods.

Comment: The only change to interfaces I could find in 8.0 is that they can now carry default code for functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods | I found nothing about access modifiers. If this is a thing, it is older then 8.0

Comment: @Christopher It is not hard to show that it is not a pre c# 8 thing: the `IFoobar` interface does not compile with younger versions, whereas it does with the newest. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6uJ4k

Comment: @MauritsMoeys Your example has the Access Modifiers marked as invalid.

Comment: @Christopher Make sure you are attempting it with an environment targeting C#8

Comment: @Christopher yes, that's because the compiler in that fiddler is set to .NET v4.7.2 ;). Change it to .net core 3 and that changes

Comment: @JonathonChase: If I could find the option for that, I would do so. Also Default functions are clearly marked differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am aware that using explicit interface implementation will implement the members, but for pre-c#8 interface members that wasn't strictly the only way. Why is this different with the new members?

[It appears this is by design](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-04-18.md#implicitly-implementing-non-public-interface-members). Here's the relevant text:

> **Implicitly implementing non-public interface members**
>
> Would we allow non-public interface members to be implemented implicitly? If so, what is required of the accessibility of the implementing method? Some options:
>
> - Must be public
> - Must be the exact same accessibility
> - Must be at least as accessible
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> For now, let's simply not allow it. Only public interface members can be implicitly implemented (and only by public members). We can relax as we think through it.

Obviously interface methods with access modifiers won't exactly play by the same rules as previous version interface members, as those can only be public.

As for why it's this way, that's a question for the designers. The wording from the LDM doesn't make it sound like this is set in stone, either. So *maybe* implicitly implemented access-modified members will allowed in the future.

For now, the way to implement this interface would be to do so explicitly, like so:

```
public interface IFoobar
{   // these members are all valid
    protected string Protected { get; set; }
    internal string Internal { get; set; }
    static string Static { get; set; }
}

public class Foobar : IFoobar
{
    string IFoobar.Protected {get;set;}
    string IFoobar.Internal {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: They do seem to understand very well **how** dangerous any implicit thing can be. You can always add implicitly later. You can never remove it, however.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Even though conceptually I haven't learnt a lot as to *why* it is like it is, but technically you've answered every part of my question. Cheers.

Comment: @MauritsMoeys At the end of the day, I believe it's mostly to allow for the ability to change an interface without breaking all current implementors. The extra modifiers are there to ease the implementation of those default implementations over a potential interface hierarchy. At least, that's my best bet towards it. This is a feature that I intend to only use if it's somehow the easier of more terrifying options.