# using public, protected internal, protected, internal, private protected in interfaces C#10

Tags: c#, interface, access-modifiers, c#-10.0

I know that beginning from C#8, access modifiers were added for interfaces since before that all the members were implicitly public.
Then it appears that beginning with C#8 they did not let implicit implementations of members in implememting classes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734707/using-static-internal-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-interfaces-c-sharp-8)  or [here](https://www.techpointfunda.com/2020/08/interface-access-modifiers-csharp.html) but Clearly as of now implicit implementations **are** allowed since the following code compiles

```
public interface CS8 {
    public void jj();
    protected internal void jj1();
    protected void jj2();
    internal void jj3();
    private protected void jj4();
}
public class ThisOne : CS8 {
    public void jj() {
        Console.WriteLine("8888");
    }
    public void jj1() {
        Console.WriteLine("7777");
    }
    public void jj2() {
        Console.WriteLine("6666");
    }
    public void jj3() {
        Console.WriteLine("5555");
    }
    public void jj4() {
        Console.WriteLine("4444");
    }
}
```

I have been scouring the internet but can not find a clear answer
*Why access modifiers were added for interfaces if the logic behind them has always been that they have to be public?*
*Why did they also add ability to implement the members inside the interface itself?*
If you could show it to me maybe on an example for each modifier that would be great.

I can only imagine it is so you can control from where what implemented methods are accessible eben though all of the members regardless of the access modifier have to be implemented.

P.S
I apologize this is 2 questions.

Comment: The ability to implement members within the interface allows you to offer a default implementation to any class that implements the interface. In other words, it allows for code re-use.  Private and protected members are allowed for refactoring these implementations into smaller methods that you might not want to expose outside the interface. See [this article](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/11/c-8-interfaces-public-private-and.html)

Comment: @JohnWu, Okay so I have read it.
It tells about the private members but does not go deep into protected members and does niot tell anything about the other access modifiers

Answer (score 0):

Default implementations were added so interfaces could be updated without breaking the code of implementing classes so clients that use the interface as public APIs would not need to update their classes and add new methods properties etc. yet still get the new functionality.
private modifier became allowed so you could use them when working with default implementations.
protected was added to provide ability to extend the already defined default implementation.